# Eclipse CDT - Which extension point to provide per-file build settings?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

In eclipse, my plugin is trying to programmatically set the build settings (defines, include paths) for each C/C++ source file separately. I have found the CExternalSettingsProvider extension point, but the `getSettings` method only receives the build configuration and an IProject. Is there an extension point with a method that receives the actual file being built, so that individual settings can be provided for it?