# How can I add language setting entries to existing CDT eclipse projects?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am following the steps found [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/Developer/FAQ#How_do_I_contribute_Include.2FLibrary_paths_or_Macros_to_a_project_configuration_using_LanguageSettingsProvider_extension_point.3F) to try to add build settings to files in existing Eclipse CDT projects using the LanguageSettingsProvider extension point, but my settings provider doesn't seem to show in the UI, and its methods aren't queried for settings.

I previously succeeded in adding settings to a project using [an external settings provider](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/Developer/FAQ#How_do_I_contribute_Include.2FLibrary_paths_or_Macros_to_a_project_configuration_using_externalSettingsProvider_extension_point.3F), but I [couldn't find a way to add file-specific settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59861100/eclipse-cdt-which-extension-point-to-provide-per-file-build-settings).

I have implemented a subclass of LanguageSettingsSerializableProvider (let's call it MyProvider), and added it to my plugin.xml thus:

```xml
    <extension
         point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.LanguageSettingsProvider">
      <provider
            class="com.example.MyProvider"
            id="MyProvider_id"
            name="I would like to see this in the UI">
         <language-scope id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.gcc"/>
         <language-scope id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.g++"/>
      </provider>
    </extension>
```

The class is implemented approximately thus:

```java
    public class MyProvider
                       extends LanguageSettingsSerializableProvider
                       implements ILanguageSettingsProvider,
                                  IResourceChangeListener,
                                  ILanguageSettingsEditableProvider,
                                  ILanguageSettingsBroadcastingProvider {
        /** The ID of this settings provider */
        public static final String MY_PROVIDER_ID = "MyProvider_id"; //$NON-NLS-

        /**
         * Constructor. Initialises super class with appropriate values.
         */
        public MyProvider() {
            super( MY_PROVIDER_ID , Messages.UiLabel );
        }

        @Override
        public String getId() {
            return MY_PROVIDER_ID ;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return Messages.UiLabel;
        }

        @Override
        public List<ICLanguageSettingEntry> getSettingEntries(ICConfigurationDescription cfgDescription, IResource resource, String languageId) {
            //breakpoint on this line that never gets hit...
            return super.getSettingEntries( cfgDescription, resource, languageId );
        }

        ...

    }
```

The real implementation contains some other logic to actually create the settings entries, including registering itself as a resource change listener. The `resourceChanged` code works fine, calls `setSettingsEntries`, and then `serializeSettings`. However, `getSettingEntries` is never called to obtain these settings.

**Is there something I'm missing?**

My guess is the plugin.xml is lacking something, but I'm not sure what. There are paragraphs of guidance in the various interfaces that the class implements, but one simple working example would be worth more than a thousand words. I've tried looking at the xml for the built-in settings providers (e.g. `GCCBuiltinCompilerSettingsMinGW`), but they're defined alongside a lot of other parts of CDT, and it's hard to tell which bits are relevant to my use case.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was:

```java
    someMethod {
        final IProject myProject = getProjectFromSomewhere();
        final ICProjectDescription projDesc = CoreModel.getDefault().getProjectDescription( myProject );
        for (ICConfigurationDescription config : projDesc.getConfigurations()) {
            try {
                ensureMySettingsProvidedFor( (ILanguageSettingsProvidersKeeper) config );
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                logger.log( Level.WARNING, "Unexpected class was not a keeper of language settings:" + config.getClass().getName(), e );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Will ensure my settings provider is registered as a settings provider for...
     * @param settingsKeeper ...the given configuration.
     */
    public static void ensureMySettingsProvidedFor(final ILanguageSettingsProvidersKeeper settingsKeeper) {
        if (settingsKeeper instanceof CConfigurationDescriptionCache) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Got non-writable cached settings. We can't update this!! "
                    + "How do we get a writeable version?");
            return;
        }
        for ( ILanguageSettingsProvider provider : settingsKeeper.getLanguageSettingProviders() ) {
            if (MyProvider.MY_PROVIDER_ID.equals( provider.getId() )) {
                return;
            }
        }
        addMyProvider( settingsKeeper );
    }

    /**
     * Adds my language settings provider to the given configuration by means of its ID.
     * @param settingsKeeper The existing configuration.
     */
    private static void addMyProvider( final ILanguageSettingsProvidersKeeper settingsKeeper ) {
        List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
        for ( ILanguageSettingsProvider provider : settingsKeeper.getLanguageSettingProviders() ) {
            ids.add( provider.getId() );
        }
        ids.add(MyProvider.MY_PROVIDER_ID);
        List<ILanguageSettingsProvider> newProviders = LanguageSettingsManager.createLanguageSettingsProviders( ids.toArray( new String[ids.size()] ) );
        settingsKeeper.setLanguageSettingProviders(newProviders);
    }
```

It doesn't feel like the best answer, but it seems to work most of the time.
One problem is knowing when to do this such that it happens for all projects that don't yet have the provider, but doesn't get called repeatedly, or too often.
Another problem is that we sometimes get a `CConfigurationDescriptionCache`, and then the code can't do anything.

I'm open to better solutions.